# How do you include a javascript variable in a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html

I have pretty simple code

```
<input type="hidden" name=passtophp value=variable>
```

The variable is created in javascript in the head of the document. Unfortunately when I put in the variable name it is captured as a string and passed through instead of the variable's actual value. How can I pass through the variable's value? Thank you!!

Comment: Can't tell what you're asking here. Needs more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myVariable = 'myValue';
document.getElementById('passtophp').value = myVariable ;
```

Ensure you specifty an ID on the hidden field though.

```
<input type="hidden" name='passtophp' id='passtophp' />
```